# How do I change a UIButton background color dynamically in UIKit when type is custom and corner style is capsule?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to change the background color of a custom button.

This is the button I have declared in my storyboard:

[image]

And this is the code I am using to set the background color:

`myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen`

And this is the result:

[image]

I'm assuming there must be a way to programmatically access the custom background to set the fill color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

`myButton.configuration!.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen`

Answer (score 0):

myButton.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).